# Using Amazon EBS like S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Is it possible to use EBS like S3? By that I mean can you allow users to download files from a link like you can in S3?

The reason for this is because my videos NEED to be on the same domain/server to work correctly. I am creating a Virtual Reality video website however, IOS does not support cross-origin resource sharing through WebGL (which is used to create VR).

Because of this, my S3 bucket file system will not work as it will be classed as cross origin, but looking into EBS briefly it seems that it attaches to the all your instances as local storage which would get past the cross-origin problem I am facing.

Would it be simply like a folder on my web server, that could be reached by 'www.domain.com/ebs-file-system/videos/video.mp4'?

Thanks in advance for any comments.

Comment: *"seems that it attaches to the all your instances as local storage"*  It attaches to *one* of your instances.

Comment: may be just run sync from ESB to S3? AWS CLI is preinstall on any instances. Internal AWS traffic is free.

Answer (score 0):

**Amazon S3 CORS**

You can configure your Amazon S3 bucket to support [Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS)](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/cors.html):

> **Cross-origin resource sharing (CORS)** defines a way for client web applications that are loaded in one domain to interact with resources in a different domain. With CORS support in Amazon S3, you can build rich client-side web applications with Amazon S3 and **selectively allow cross-origin access to your Amazon S3 resources**.

**CloudFront Behaviours**

Another option is to use Amazon CloudFront, which can present multiple systems as a single URL. For example, `example.com/video` could point to an S3 bucket, while `example.com/stream` could point to a web server. This should circumvent CORS problems.

See:

- [Format of URLs for CloudFront Objects](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/LinkFormat.html)
- [Values that You Specify When You Create or Update a Web Distribution](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/distribution-web-values-specify.html#DownloadDistValuesPathPattern)

**Worst Case**

Worst case, you could serve *everything* via your EC2 instance. You could copy your S3 content to the instance (eg using the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/) `aws s3 sync` command) and serve it to your users. However, this negates all the benefits that Amazon S3 provides.